# How to create random number for a document only on first build then reuse it in subsequent builds?

Tags: compiling, auxiliary-files

I want to create unique ID numbers for my documents, and am doing so using a random number generator like this:

```
\usepackage[first=1, last=100000000]{lcg}
\newcommand{\random}{\rand\arabic{rand}}
```

However, really I would like to create a random number once on first build of the document and then have the same number used from then on in subsequent builds. Can I do this? and if so, how?

Comment: Hi, this is an interesting question and it looks like you've received a good answer.  However, wouldn't it be easier to just create the random number some other way and hard-code it into your document?  For example, you could use the following website.  https://www.random.org/integers/

Comment: See the `seed` option for lcg (page 2 of manual).

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Can you expand on how the `seed` option will help?  The OP wants an initial random integer that is then retained for subsequent builds.  I assume you are suggesting to use a seed value.  But if the OP must enter a random seed, then they might as well just input a random document number instead, correct?  Now if the OP needs many persistent random numbers generated in a single document, then I can see how a seed value would be useful.

Comment: @James, yes, one could create the number some other way, but it imposes the burden to do this on all users of a document template I am creating. The solution provided hides this extra step from the users who then don't have to think about it. It's pretty cool.

Comment: @crobar: I understand now.  I didn't realize you were creating this for other users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save the generated random number to a file named `\jobname.rid`, then every time you build the document, it reads that file.  If you delete the .rid file then a new random number is generated:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{myclass.cls}
\LoadClass{article}

% ID code
\ExplSyntaxOn
% Create a variable "\c_crobar_id_file_str" that contains the .rid file name:
\str_const:Nx \c_crobar_id_file_str { \c_sys_jobname_str . rid }
% Create a macro "\crobar@set@ID" that assigns its argument to the integer "\c_crobar_random_int":
\cs_new_protected:Npn \crobar@set@ID #1
  { \int_const:Nn \c_crobar_random_int {#1} }
% Check if the .rid file exists:
\file_if_exist:nTF { \c_crobar_id_file_str }
  {
    % If it does, input it:
    \file_input:n { \c_crobar_id_file_str }
  }
  {
    % If the file doesn't exist, create one and assign using \crobar@set@ID
    \crobar@set@ID { \int_rand:nn { 1 } { 100000000 } }
    % Then open the .rid file for writing (iow = IO/Write)
    \iow_open:Nn \g_tmpa_iow { \c_crobar_id_file_str }
    % Now write "\crobar@set@ID{<random number>}" to the .rid file
    \iow_now:Nx \g_tmpa_iow
      { \crobar@set@ID { \int_use:N \c_crobar_random_int } }
    % And close the .rid file
    \iow_close:N \g_tmpa_iow
  }
% Finally, create a user-level command \random that writes the integer \c_crobar_random_int
\cs_new:Npn \random { \int_to_arabic:n { \c_crobar_random_int } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
% ID code
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{myclass}
\begin{document}
This document ID is \random.
\end{document}
```

Running the document on my machine resulted in:

> [image]

Comment: This could be the solution, thanks! However, is it possible to use an alternative file name/extension so that one can still delete the default aux file if necessary (or delete the ID file only)? Also, can this be used in a cls file to hide the complexity from users?

Comment: @crobar  Changed it to use a dedicated file.  The code is the same whether it's in a class file, or in the preamble, as long as `\random` is not used before the random number is assigned.

Comment: very impressive, thanks. Unfortunately I'll have to google every command to fully understand it!

Comment: @crobar I added some comments along the code to (hopefully) make it easier to understand.  The code uses mostly `expl3` interface functions, so if you want to take a deeper look into how it works, I suggest looking for these functions in [`interface3.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) instead.  If there's any specific part you are having trouble to understand, feel free to ask

Comment: I've been struggling a bit to use this. I tried putting the example all in one file and building it, but it failed. I then tried splitting into a cls and tex file with everything up to `\end{filecontents*}` in the cls.  The first error I get is like `! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \crobar`. I'm also curious about why there is no \begin{filecontents*}? Also I understand this is using LaTeX3 code, and after having searched, I'm not really sure what I need to do to use it in LaTeX2E?

Comment: @crobar Sorry, the `\begin{filecontents*}` got gobbled by the markdown.  I fixed it.  To add the code in the body of the document you need to write `\makeatletter` before it, and `\makeatother` after (this is done by default in classes and packages).  Yes, this is `expl3`/LaTeX3 code, and it should work natively in LaTeX2e.

Comment: ok, thanks! And just to be clear, then, the `filecontents` environment is only required if you want this example as one contained file, but should be removed if creating a separate cls file manually?

Comment: @crobar Exactly

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but extending the idea of an ID into the visual space:

Since a glyph in a font is (mapable to) a code-number, setting the randomizer to a Unicode codeblock, say, `\int_rand:nn { 19968 } { 40938 }`, running it multiple times and typesetting it in an appropriate font, a many-digit ID number can become an ID "phrase":

[image: ID word]

There are many blocks:

[image: ID word2]

Possible use-case could be to replace GUIDs or larger, representing them in a more compact form.

Answer (score 2):

Try to load `\jobname.rid`, and if it fails, create a random ID to a command `\docID` and store its definition in `\jobname.rid`.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[first=1, last=100000000]{lcg}

\IfFileExists{\jobname.rid}
  {\input{\jobname.rid}}
  {\rand
   \def\docID{\arabic{rand}}
   % writing \def\docID{<ID>} to \jobname.rid
   \newwrite\docIDoutput
   \immediate\openout\docIDoutput=\jobname.rid
   \write\docIDoutput{\protect\def\protect\docID{\docID}}}

\begin{document}

ID: \docID

\end{document}
```

Caution: random seed seams to depend on time up to minute (so it is the same in runs within the same minute).